# What does /M meaning in a hunspell dictionary

Tags: dictionary, hunspell

I added a word "isoceles" to the hunspell dictionary and it worked OK. I noticed that many entries have a flag /M (and there are other flags), but I couldn't find documentation of the flags anywhere. Are these flags something I need to know just to add a handful of words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is arbitrary (not that it is like "male gender" or something) and the meaning is given in affix file next to the .dic file.

For example [the open office one](http://www.openoffice.org/lingucomponent/english.aff) or [some github one](https://github.com/wooorm/dictionaries/blob/main/dictionaries/en/index.aff) have the same meaning -> the word can have `'s`. So the library can generate other possible forms of words.. For `son` it can generate `son's` and so on.